# Does Log.isLoggable returns wrong values?

Tags: android, logging, android-emulator, logcat

When I was writing a log wrapper for my android application I noticed a strange behavior of androids Log.isLoggable method. Executing following code:

```
final String TAG = "Test";
Log.v(TAG, "verbose is active: " + Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE));
Log.d(TAG, "debug is active: " + Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG));
Log.i(TAG, "info is active: " + Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.INFO));
Log.w(TAG, "warn is active: " + Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.WARN));
Log.e(TAG, "error is active: " + Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.ERROR));
```

produces following LogCat output:

```
VERBOSE/Test(598): verbose is active: false
DEBUG/Test(598): debug is active: false
INFO/Test(598): info is active: true
WARN/Test(598): warn is active: true
ERROR/Test(598): error is active: true
```

Why do I get verbose and debug is not active although I produce these outputs using verbose and debug logging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All log levels are written to logcat regardless of what the current log level is. The `isLogabble()` method can be used as an optimization for your apps to prevent sending unneeded log statements to logcat. You can also use the `adb logcat` command to filter a subset of the logging levels even if the logging is set to verbose (see https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).

Answer (score 13):

If you read the information on [Log.isLoggable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), you'll notice that the default logging level is `INFO`.  Anything less than that (`DEBUG` and `VERBOSE`) will cause this method to return `false`.  This is why your resulting output shows these two as `false`.

All `Log.*` calls are logged to the logcat.  Calling `Log.isLoggable()` is simply a way for you to tune logging.  It's not required.  Typically, you'll call `Log.isLoggable()` prior to the actual `Log.*` call to determine whether to log it or not.

You can tune your logging per `TAG` if you choose, either with a prop file or via adb.  The nice thing about this is you can dynamically turn logging up/down/off for each individual `TAG` in your app without the need for manually commenting out Log lines, or implementing your own checks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
    Log.v(TAG, "verbose is active: " + Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LOG will always be print in the logcat no matter what Log.isloggable() return.