# java.util.logging.Logger swallowing logs

Tags: java, logging

I am using `java.util.logging.Logger` and I want to enable all log levels. I thought the following would work:

```
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

But apparently it doesn't. Only `INFO` level logging statements are taking effect, and others are being swallowed.

How do I enable all log levels?

Comment: I had similar experience with android native logging and got no answer so far. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468444/bug-in-android-util-log-or-in-my-sample-code-thinking

Comment: @k3b, that's surprising. I hope at least answer to this problem is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably the log handler that is swallowing the log records. You need to set the log level on your handlers too. For example:

```
for (Handler handler : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
  handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}
```

Or you can read your configuration from a `logging.properties` file (just put it in your CLASSPATH root), or you can read a `logging.properties`-style configuration from a stream using `LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(someInputStream)`.

Comment: I tried setting log level to `Level.ALL` on all handlers. No difference.

Comment: Make sure you get the root logger. Your logger has an empty set of handlers, it defers log handling to its parent loggers.