# Android Proguard not removing all log messages

Tags: android, logging, obfuscation, proguard

I want to create an obfuscated android application. I use ProGuard for that. I would like to automatically remove all the Log.* messages. How can I do that? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435773/android-proguard-removing-all-log-statements-and-merging-packages) post but I still get them. (I use a decompiler to check the obfuscation).
 The proguard-project.txt is the following:

```
-injars       libs/In.jar
-outjars      libs/Out.jar
#-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars C:/Users/thomas/android-sdks/platforms/android-7/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This only remove all debug `Log.d(TAG, "...");` and error `Log.e(TAG, "...")` calls:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

To remove all log calls, simply use this:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

Comment: WARNING: Doing so will remove the wait() method of all objects, because *; includes all method of Log, including the wait() from Object class! This will surely cause weird side effects.

Comment: Do not ever do -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
to avoid side effects. It will also be made an error soon in the new R8

Answer (score 18):

The default android Proguard configuration disables optimisation.  To enable it, in your project's project.properties file use proguard-android-optimize.txt instead of proguard-android.txt

Answer (score 12):

For anyone that can't seem to wrap their head around pro-guard, you have to make sure you do two things.

1: From @yorkw

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

2: From @Gallal

In your project's project.properties file use:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

instead of

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

This is because you have two proguard options "out of the box" since they are included in the sdk

`android-adk > tools > proguard`

Which contains two files:

```
proguard-android.txt
proguard-android-optimize.txt
```

Hope that helps someone else down the line.

Comment: The `project.properties` file is that (now) called `local.properties`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything is different now if you use android studio. Don't think it's even called proguard. Think its called "minify" which allows proguard to run. That said. THESE INSTRUCTION ARE ONLY FOR ECLIPSE.

Comment: For some reason I still see **Log** calls in my class.

Comment: I found that log calls were removed only in release buildType

Answer (score 10):

If you have Android Studio, you have to modify the `build.gradle` of your main application.

In your gradle file, you have to specify the usage of `proguard-android-optimize.txt` as the default file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        // With the file below, it does not work!
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Actually, in the default `proguard-android.txt` file, optimization is disabled with the two flags:

```
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

The `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file does not add those lines, so now `assumenosideeffects` can work.

Then, as said in other answers for Eclipse or else, you just have to add to your main proguard file the line:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

Comment: dontpreverify is not strictly related to optimization.  "Only when eventually targeting Android, it is not necessary, so you can then switch it off to reduce the processing time a bit." https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage