# android-maven-plugin: Disable debug build for apk

Tags: android, debugging, maven, build, maven-plugin

I am not clear about the exact procedure for disabling debug build while building with android-maven-plugin:

I understand that the export wizard with ADT(21.1) will automatically disable debugging but it is broken as BuildConfig.DEBUG always returns true and my logging used to depend on it. (Now I have my own property for logging defined in my maven build profiles.)

So if I have to disable debugging using android-maven-plugin, what is the the right way to do it?

I use the following plugins:

1. maven-compiler-plugin
2. maven-jarsigner-plugin
3. proguard-maven-plugin
4. android-maven-plugin with zipalign goal and configuration.

I am not sure whether signing and zipaligning automatically disables debugging because I see the following line in the maven output:

```
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:apk (default-apk) @ stackx ---
[INFO] Copying local assets files to combined assets directory.
[INFO] Enabling debug build for apk.
```

Is there an explicit way to disable debugging?

Comment: You may want to check this link http://antew.com/?p=150

Comment: check here http://mavenforu.blogspot.com/2014/04/maven-android-plugin.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check out [changelog](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog) for Android Maven Plugin 3.5.0 - released 2012-12-18:

***ATTENTION***

Since non-release builds are now debuggable by default you NEED TO ensure that the release parameter is set to true in your release build.

In the pom this would be e.g.

```
<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
<artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <release>true</release>
```

or you could activate on the command line with e.g

```
mvn clean deploy -Dandroid.release=true
```

or if you use the release plugin just add the above pom config to the release profile.

### Source Code:

[com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/phase09package/ApkMojo.java](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/phase09package/ApkMojo.java#L1149)

### Related Pull Request:

- [Non-release builds will now automatically be debuggable](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/149)
- [Support BuildConfig generation](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/123)

### Off Topic:

For logging management, A more elegant and strategic way is to use Proguard remove all log call at project release phase, see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390466/android-proguard-not-removing-all-log-messages/12396486#12396486) for more details.

Comment: this worked, thanks. regarding log management using proguard, I have tried it but  I an messing it up somewhere as I still see log statements

Comment: I've added <release>true</release> to my profile just as you specified above but release builds still seem be setting debug? The second method of using -Dandroid.release=true seems to work, but any ideas why it's not working in the pom?  Also tried setting it as shown in http://antew.com/?p=150 but no luck.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your pom.xml, if you follow the sample project and set `<release>true</release>` in release profile, to active it, run `mvn clean install -Prelease`, or if you use maven-release-plugin, run `mvn release:prepare`.

Comment: it works for me, thanks.
I can clearly see while building:
Enabling release build for apk.

Comment: Thanks very much. Helped me to deploy to the store. I don't understand what's the intention of this change because when I say debug yes or no, why is that not enough.