# Want to publish my .apk file on playstore

Tags: android, apk, release, google-play, debug-mode

I want to publish my app on play store. First it asked me to signed my .apk file and I did it by using debug.keystore and now again i'm trying to upload to .apk and now its saying that "You created this apk in debug mode, you have to create it in release mode" I tried this method too but still i got no success. Can anyone help me plzzz?

Comment: Check [doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681282/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-was-signed-in-debug-mode-you-need-to-sign-your-apk-in)

Comment: debug.keystore is only for testing, hence the "debug", you would need to follow http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode to sign the APK to a release keystore, before Google Play will accept your compiled APK file. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own signed key in order to publish app. It is very simple and can be done with Eclipse.

Just follow this quick guide:

1. Right click on your project in Eclipse -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package
2. Click Next
3. Select "create new keystore", choose location, enter password
4. Click Next and fill needed fields. Write 25 years in validity. (it is the minimum)
5. Click next and chose where you want to place apk for Google Play

Thats all. Next time when you want to update your app just select "use existing key" in step 3.