# Signed APK (Android application) can't be published to Google Play, debugging is still ON for some reason

Tags: android, debugging, apk

I have delivered Android debug APK to customer who has signed it and tried to publish it to Google Play.
It failed, saying that debugging has to be turned off. Original message is in Dutch so I am not sure about it exactly, but this is it:
upload mislukt
U heeft een APK geüpload waarvoor foutopsporing kan worden uitgevoerd.
Uit veiligheidsoverwegingen moet u foutopsporing uitschakelen voordat de APK kan worden gepubliceerd in Google Play.

I've always produced signed APK directly from Netbeans, but this is not the case, customer needs to sign it.

I read something about debuggable flag in Android manifest, which I don't use at the moment and by documentation, it is set to false by default anyway.

Can somebody help me what needs to be changed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20051192/3565972. Solution is to explicitly set `android:debuggable="false"` inside the `<application>` tag

Comment: OK, I will try that as you suggest

Comment: I guess this is going to help me ... will try out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055961/android-maven-plugin-disable-debug-build-for-apk

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Problem for 2 days ago. I've solved with gradle build config. What i'm did was, i insert this line `debuggable false` in build.gradle

```
release {
    debuggable false
    jniDebugBuild false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```

and change the BuildVariants in android studio from 'debug' to 'release'. I've read about the AndroidManifest thing, but that not worked for me.

Comment: I use Eclipse or Netbeans and Maven build

Comment: Still don't understand why does it work when I sign my app immediately by using Netbeans Export wizard... what could be the difference there?

Comment: did you compile in release mode? (Eclipse or Netbeans)

Comment: Ferit, that's pretty old thread, release through Export wizard works perfectly.

Comment: But you are right, I think I have to go through Android Tools in Eclipse and release unsigned package. Can anybody confirm?

Comment: Yes, this is the case, Export Unsigned Package, that's release mode, which will be signed later on. My problem now is that I need to release different maven profile than Default...