# Rather odd behaviour of Log

Tags: android, android-logcat

I wrote a very simple Android Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate() Log call 1");
        Log.d("SMS", "onCreate() Log call 2");
        Log.d("TEST", "onCreate() Log call 3");

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("TAG", "onDestroy() Log call 1");
        Log.d("SMS", "onDestroy() Log call 2");
        Log.d("TEST", "onDestroy() Log call 3");

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I would expect this to generate 6 log messages (3 from `onCreate()`, 3 from `onDestroy()`). Here is the logcat:

```
04-14 17:31:58.363: D/TAG(18084): onCreate() Log call 1
04-14 17:31:58.363: D/TEST(18084): onCreate() Log call 3
04-14 17:31:59.905: D/TAG(18084): onDestroy() Log call 1
04-14 17:31:59.905: D/TEST(18084): onDestroy() Log call 3
```

As can be seen, the lines with the tag "SMS" don't get through. This is not, as far as I can tell a documented thing. The question is, why?

EDIT: More details on the answer.

A rather good answer is given below by Matthew Burke. In short, on the basis of the source code for `logd_write.c`, it seems that:

- `Log` requests with the following tags are automatically redirected to the `radio` log:

  - `HTC_RIL`
  - tags starting with `RIL`
  - `AT`
  - `GSM`
  - `STK`
  - `CDMA`
  - `PHONE`
  - `SMS`
- No `Log` requests are redirected to the `events` log (or the `system` log, see also http://elinux.org/Android_Logging_System)
- All other `Log` requests go to the `main` log, the one that is usually monitored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have read the documentation for `logcat` before I started hunting through source.  According to `logcat`'s documentation:

> The Android logging system keeps multiple circular buffers for log messages, and not all of the log messages are sent to the default circular buffer.

Messages with a tag of `SMS` are sent to the radio buffer, not the main buffer.  Hence you won't see them unless you go out of your way to do so.  If you run the command:

> `adb logcat -b radio`

you should see your missing log messages.  The above information can be found in https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html.

---

Now, for those of you interested in code spelunking, below is my original answer:

The methods in the `Log` class are all wrappers around `println_native` which is a JNI method.
`println_native` performs some validation of its parameters and then calls `__android_log_buf_write`.

Now this latter method compares the tag parameter (from the original `Log.d` call) against several hard-coded strings (with the tag *SMS* being one of this list) and if it finds a match, winds up writing the log message to a different file!

By the way, other tags that get rerouted are GSM, STK, PHONE, CDMA, and a few others.

Relevant source can be read in

- http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/util/Log.java.htm
- https://pdroid.googlecode.com/svn/android-2.3.4_r1/trunk/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_Log.cpp
- https://in-the-box.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/InTheBoxSim/liblog/logd_write.c
- http://www.takatan.net/lxr/source/drivers/staging/android/logger.h#L33

These aren't the official links and may disappear at some point.  I'll try and track down the official links and edit this later this evening.

Comment: Good stuff - in your hunting, have you found a formal (or even semi formal) list of which tags get pushed to the radio and events logs as opposed to the main (default) log? I particularly liked the line `/* XXX: This needs to go! */` in source for logd_write.c - other than that piece of code is this documented anywhere?

Comment: The only thing I've seen are the hard-coded strings in the source code for logd_write.c.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the list of tags from the source code - could you check that they look correct to you?

Comment: I received a notification to review the edit you made.  However, I don't see anyway of approving/incorporating the edit. When I get home this evening, I'll edit the post directly and include your changes.

Comment: I tried for a second time to add information to your answer to complete it, and after a couple of hours it had disappeared, no idea why. So I've added the list inferred from the source code to the question, would be interested to know if you agree.

Comment: Ack! Sorry! Yes, I agree.  I was going to add that info to my answer, but I got sidetracked.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Ignore this, I'm apparently quite off base according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948402/321697).

<s>So I thought this was interesting, and after digging through the source, I ended up finding out about [`Log.isLoggable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html):</s>

> Checks to see whether or not a log for the specified tag is loggable
>   at the specified level. The default level of any tag is set to INFO.
>   This means that any level above and including INFO will be logged.
>   Before you make any calls to a logging method you should check to see
>   if your tag should be logged. You can change the default level by
>   setting a system property: 'setprop log.tag. '
>   Where level is either VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ASSERT, or
>   SUPPRESS. SUPPRESS will turn off all logging for your tag. You can
>   also create a local.prop file that with the following in it:
>   'log.tag.=' and place that in /data/local.prop.
>
> Parameters 
>   tag
>   The tag to check. 
> level   The level to check. 
> Returns
>   Whether or not that this is allowed to be logged.

Apparently some tags are not allowed at certain log levels, seemingly defined in `/data/local.prop`, but there must be some system level properties file I haven't found yet. You can check against it using something like this, though:

```
boolean isLoggableV = Log.isLoggable("SMS", Log.VERBOSE);
boolean isLoggableD = Log.isLoggable("SMS", Log.DEBUG);
boolean isLoggableI = Log.isLoggable("SMS", Log.INFO);
boolean isLoggableW = Log.isLoggable("SMS", Log.WARN);
boolean isLoggableE = Log.isLoggable("SMS", Log.ERROR);
boolean isLoggableA = Log.isLoggable("SMS", Log.ASSERT);

Log.v("LogTest", String.format("Verbose: %b Debug: %b Info: %b Warn: %b Error: %b Assert: %b", isLoggableV, isLoggableD, isLoggableI, isLoggableW, isLoggableE, isLoggableA));
```

Which for me returned the following:

```
Verbose: false Debug: false Info: true Warn: true Error: true Assert: true
```

So you can log the tag `SMS` at a log level of `INFO` and above, but not `VERBOSE` or `DEBUG`.

I have to assume this is to prevent applications from accidentally logging personal information, but it seems like a fairly crude way of doing so.

Comment: Whew! I'm not living in an alternative universe with unpredictable Log behaviour. Any idea how to get a list of these "restricted" tags other than experimentation. Or is it phone dependent?

Comment: Actually, the mystery continues. From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7948402/321697) it appears `isLoggable()` isn't what I thought it was, and logging the "SMS" tag with a log level of `INFO` or above *still* fails. I honestly don't know at this point. @.@

Comment: Aaaarg - I had missed that complication, but it summarises all other attempts to understand this one! If you come across anything, I'm itching to give the bounty to a good and complete answer!